# OCR for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, ocr

I know that this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745/open-source-windows-mobile-ocr-library) but that was over 3 years ago and some things might have changed. I need an OCR library for Windows mobile (6.1) to detect characters (one up to 3 words) from camera's photos.

I am kind of aware of that it would involve HUGE amount of coding if I would have to write it on my own so I would really appreciate finding some kind of libraries that would help me do this.

I would prefer C# libraries but C++ will be also good (if nothing else is to be found).

**EDIT**

Ok so I have managed to sort this out partially: I have downloaded project from [Alex Karpus' site](http://alexkarpus.com/opencv/) where he presents his job with openCV on Windows Mobile (and iPhone). I didn't try to port openCV to Windows Mobile but I did manage (and it took me quite significant amount of time) to successfully deploy openCV onto my Windows Mobile phone. Now I am looking for some hints how can I do the OCR while I already have the openCV on the phone :).

If you have any suggestion please post it either here on in my question about Artificial Neural Networks' OCR [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580229/can-somebody-give-concrete-examplescode-of-using-artificial-neural-networks-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one built-in. Quite a few .NET OCR libraries are available commercially, but you'd probably need to talk to the developers about whether they can compile a proper version for you, because the PC assembly won't work.

You could also try to port Tesseract to C# and compile it for the phone, but that would be a non-trivial undertaking if someone else hasn't already started it.

I think you could also use one of several websites that let you upload an image and send you back an OCR'ed data. Try [www.ocrsdk.com](http://www.ocrsdk.com), it is a cloud based OCR SDK recently launched by ABBYY. It's now in closed beta so it's completely free to use.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have seen many people posted about possibilities of using web services such as this one (abby) but I would need a version that would allow me to do ocr without connecting to the web.